# Create a Miura origami pattern?

Tags: warning-messages, generative-art

I want to solve the below code to create an origami pattern

```
Manipulate [{
   {V},
   {H},
   {L},
   {S},
   {a},
   {b},
   {c},
   {d},
   {e},
   {f},
   {g},
   {h},
   {i},
   {k}
  } := {
   {Sqrt[1 + \[Micro]]},
   {Sqrt[\[Micro]]/v},
   {1/v},
   {Sqrt[1 - \[Micro]]},
   {S  k},
   {-L},
   {H},
   {S - V  H},
   {L},
   {S  L - V},
   {-S  k},
   {-S - V  H},
   {-S  L - V},
   {-L - V}
  }; Graphics3D@
   Polygon@{{
       {a, b, c, d},
       {d, c, e, f},
       {g, b, c, h},
       {c, h, i, e}
      } }[[All, All, 1]] /. Null -> 0, {\[Micro], 0, 1}]
```

[image: This is the code that I want to run.]

The link for the result is [here](https://youtu.be/QUeYOhDGm80)

This is the result that I get[image: My result is an empty box]

Please help me out with your expertise people.

Comment: Please link to (or show) the code in a form where we can copy/paste it.

Comment: Welcome to mma.SE, @genie_prabhu! You might find this useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/63039 and, I’m not confident, but I am quite sure your syntax is not accurate. Firstly, you want to define a list, as opposed to what is honestly quite a neat way of avant-garde-style input (what made you try this?), because that style of input will not work. Secondly, are your V’s all uppercase as you have them defined? It looks like the denominator in some are lowercase v to me is why I ask. See how they’re blue? Correct this, put it into a `Solve`, then `ReplaceAll` with the solution!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted the code in the required format. I saw the code in a [Mathematica one-liner competition] (https://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/17/the-mathematica-one-liner-competition/) and wanted to try it out.  The V is in smaller case as you mentioned, I tried changing it to upper case  and used  `ReplaceAll` but the result is still an empty box

Comment: @genie_prabhu name the two sets, `lhs:=rhs` then use solve to find the solution, name this `sol`, then use `ReplaceAll` on that to apply it to the set, then wrap that in the manipulate :)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is written in a style that makes it difficult to understand, but one thing is obvious: `v` must be given a value before any graphics can be displayed. Taking this into account and rewriting the code into something much simpler that I believe might be equivalent or close to equivalent to what you are trying get, I offer

```
Manipulate[
  {V, H, L, S} = {Sqrt[1 + μ], Sqrt[μ]/v, 1/v, Sqrt[1 - μ]};
  k = -L - V;
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i} = {S k, -L, H, S - V H, L, S L - V, -S k, -S - V H, -S L - V};
  Graphics3D[Polygon[{{a, b, c}, {d, c, e}, {g, b, c}, {c, h, i}}],
    Boxed -> False],
  {μ, .01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {v, .01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

This produces a graphics object that looks like a folded 2D polygon, so even if this doesn't completely answer to your question, it may help you to move you in the right direction.